# ¿Cómo limpiar eventos de un control en c#?

Tags: c#, eventos, textbox, usercontrol

Mi problema es el siguiente y encontre la solución, tengo una código que me agregar un evento en `KeyPress` y para agregar en `Validating` a cualquier caja de texto `TextBox`, una es para que valide y el otro es para que restriga, necesitaba  que la caja de texto si su primero caracter era un numero quieres decir que la persona se iba a loguear con su identificación por ende deberia bloquear todos los caracteres pero si era un correo no, se que se hubiera arreglado fácil con una condicion pero el codigo que usa funciona para cualquier caja de texto y hacer una validacion solo para una caja me daba pereza, asi que busque cómo eliminar eventos sin saber el nombre, de manera anonima y esto entonces...

Este es mi código con funciones entendidas de C#

```
  public static void RestrictNumberOnly(this TextBox control)
    {
        control.KeyPress += (object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        };
    }
```

necesitaba remover ese evento pero estaba anomino, sé que se puede así

> Agregar

```
Control.Click+= NameEvent
```

> Quitar

```
Control.Click-= NameEvent
```

Pero a mi no me funciona por tenerlo anomimo.

Comment: No respondas ninguna pregunta directamente en la pregunta o editandola. Haz una pregunta y respondela en una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

> Agregar

```
Control.Click+= NameEvent
```

> Quitar

```
Control.Click-= NameEvent
```

sino te funciona usa esto

> Funcion extendida, necesita estar en una clase estacica `static`

```
 public static void RemoveEvents(this Control b, List<String> eventos)
    {
        foreach (var item in eventos)
        {
            FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField($"Event{item}",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | 
            BindingFlags.Default);
            object obj = f1.GetValue(b);
            PropertyInfo pi = b.GetType().GetProperty("Events",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(b, null);
            list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
        }
       
    }
```

> Uso

```
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.RemoveEvents(new List<String>() { "Validating", "KeyPress" });
```

> Función Normal

```
 public void RemoveEvents(Control b, List<String> eventos)
    {
        foreach (var item in eventos)
        {
            FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField($"Event{item}",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | 
            BindingFlags.Default);
            object obj = f1.GetValue(b);
            PropertyInfo pi = b.GetType().GetProperty("Events",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(b, null);
            list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
        }
       
    }
```

> Uso

```
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    RemoveEvents(textBox,new List<String>() { "Validating", "KeyPress" });
```

> Nota

La lista que revise cómo parametros son todos los eventos que queremos eliminar

fuentes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-an-event/91853#91853

https://www.iteramos.com/pregunta/3087/como-eliminar-todos-los-manejadores-de-eventos-de-un-control

Comment: Quitar era con `-=`. Si obtuviste el código déjanos saber de dónde (por más que le hayas hecho algunas modificaciones). Ya sea de esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/a/91853/13419694 o directo del foro de MSDN. A ti también te gustaría que te den crédito por algo que se te ocurrió.

Comment: ya hice todas las correcciones, Gracias :)